# copying span text to a hidden input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying for about two week to find an answer for this. Ok. I am trying to copy the spans text(which changes) and put it in an inputs value. The reason I am doing this is so I can be email ed what the user selects. Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/qfdvE/

Please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: looks like a new account.... I have already answered this question in the chat. http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/T3Fj8/1/ user http://stackoverflow.com/users/1354104/hunter-mitchell http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3482157#3482157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#test_select").change(function(){
        $("#dropdown").val($(this).val());        
    });    
});
​
```

**EDIT** : If you want to get the value of the span (the decorated dropdown) and set in the hidden, you need to update this part of code in your sample. The newly added line is bolded

```
$lists.live('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $lists.not(this).find('ul:visible').hide()
    var $tgt = $(e.target);
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('fast');
    if ($tgt.is('li')) {
        $(this).find('span').html($tgt.html());
        var value=$tgt.attr('rel');    

        $("#dropdown").val(value);   //This line is what you want

        $('#test_select').val( value);
    }   

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will not be able to accept the answer in a couple of days, because I am not able to be on my computer.